# When Zooming Personal Geodatabase Feature Class one or more layers failed to draw?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, personal-geodatabase

When i joined two different feature class attribute table while i have to zooming the PGDB feature class , drawing error will come. I have attached an example image to show the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see your spatial table is called 2_2? ? If this is the case, I don't think ArcGIS allows tables with names starting with numbers. In theory, it shouldn't even allowed you to create the feature class. If this is true, try changing the table name

Comment: if this answers your question then please mark it as answer